# Spring @Async and java CompleteFuture supply async: call bean inside asynchronous method

Tags: java, spring, java-8

I need to make an asynchronous call to a service which is injected by Spring using the autowire annotation.
I'm doing something like this

```
@Component
Public class nameListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshEvent>{
@Autowire
protected ServiceName serviceName;

@Override
@Transactional
public onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshEvent event){
  log(asyncMethod.get().longValue());
}

@Async
public CompletableFuture<Long> asyncMethod(){
 CompletableFuture<Long> result = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> serviceName.methodName());
  return result;
}
```

serviceBean configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class serviceClassConfiguration{
@Autowired
protected serviceFactory;

@Bean
public ServiceType serviceName();
   //this only creates the type with the attributes it need
   return serviceFactory.createServiceName();
}
```

The Error I'm getting says the following:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException;
Scope session is not active for the current thread;
consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend
to refer to it from a singleton;
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException;
No thread-bound request found;
Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request,
or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread&;
If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this
message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet;
In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to
expose the current request
```

If I understand the problem correctly I think that Spring injects a proxy when does dependency injection so the serviceName bean is not available in the scope of the asyncCall, is that correct?

I tried creating a new class only for the asyncMethod using prototype scope so it can be created any time is been call, and added as a bean on the listenerclass but this didnt work also.

Which workarounds could I use to manage this situation?

Best regards

Comment: `Scope session is not active for the current thread` identifies the problem.  The cause of this appears to be in the configured scope of your `ServiceName` class.  Consider including configuration details.

Answer (score 0):

`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` will run your method in a pooled thread.

That thread is completely does not received `@Transaction` around.

So you have to create and common/rollback your transaction manually